# Select statement within a cell in a database table

Tags: sql, select, database-table

I have a basic database table. I would like to implement a functionallity that would allow to insert a select query within a random cell in the table. The result of this query would then be used as as any other cell of elementary type - in my case to compare it to an another value.

The problem is that I do not know in advance how those queries look like.

Here is an example. Say I have a an incoming parameter "score", which assumes some random integer values. I would like to see if the parameter "score" falls within the range defined between the values in Col1 and Col2, and if so happens, then to return the value in Col3.

```
Table1:

Col1   Col2    Col3
5      10      first row
10     15      second row
20     30      third row
*      50      forth row

    * -> select avg(some_number) from Table2;
```

This random query can occur in any cell and is certain to return a single value. That is why I cannot use a simple JOIN statement.

Edit: Thanks Tim for suggesting to give an example.

Comment: Please show us a table definition, maybe some sample data, and desired output. I'm having trouble even finding the question here.

Comment: You might need to explain what you're trying to do, step by step. At the moment I haven't a clue! :)

Comment: From what I can tell, you are building a spreadsheet instead of db.  You would be better off with what you're wanting to do I think.  Well at least from the vagueness above.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at CASE statements in SQL, and also at virtual or symbolic columns whose value is the result of an expression or function.